# I am using NAN in javascript for onclick but it is throwing warning in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I would just add this as a comment where I found this solution but my rep is perpetually at 43 and I can't so it's a new question.

I am using this in my text input form fields where I only want numbers, I found this as a solution to a question in this forum:

```
onkeypress="if ( isNaN( String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) )) return false;"
```

This works great in Chrome but in Firefox the following error is thrown:

```
12:30:53.951 Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.
```

I really want to limit the input to only numbers.. any ideas on how to get rid of this error?

Before someone says "Duh, search the document for getPreventDefault()" it's not there, I don't use it or call it anywhere.

Comment: Is that an error or a warning? It's phrased as a warning. Why the 'jQuery' tag?

Comment: It's a warning .. I resolved it .. and discovered it wasn't causing the issue I was seeing anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, this is happening because you are using inline event handling and non-standard code for cancelling the event, which is not the standard way to wire events. Instead do it in code:

```
 yourInputField.addEventListener("keypress", function(evt){

     if(isNaN(String.fromCharCode(evt.keyCode))){
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
     } 

 });
```

Comment: Surely Firefox isn't going to stop inline event handlers - that would break an awfully large number of websites.

Comment: It's not that it's going to stop inline event handlers, but how it goes about cancelling the event (when return false is sent) seems to be the root of the problem. The standard way to stop an event is with event.preventDefault(). The error that the OP is getting seems to indicate that a non-standard event cancellation technique is being used. If the OP writes modern, standards-compliant code, he can control how the event gets cancelled. Not to mention that inline JavaScdript is SOOO 1997!

Comment: 1.  So the purpose is to just do nothing when the input is not a number. 2. I got the idea to do it this way from this website.  3.  I am a female 4.  1997 code laid the groundwork for what you see today.. and just because all the cool kids do it .. doesn't make it right

Comment: I am not trying to offend. I am telling you that you are getting an error about the return false cancelling the event and since you are coding in a very old, non-standard way, this is most likely the problem since you aren't cancelling the event properly. It really doesn't matter where you got the code from. if it's non-standard and out of date, it's non-standard and out of date. Sorry that I said "he" when you are a "she". I assumed Jo mean man.

Comment: The [html5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handler-attributes) still includes inline handlers, and says that returning false will cancel the event. So what is the standard that you are referring to that you say returning false doesn't comply with? Please quote some specific documentation.

Comment: Using inline event handlers cause events to be called and processed differently than registering them in JavaScript code. Since FireFox is providing an error to the OP indicating a problem with the way the event's default behavior is being called, the logical conclusion is to take control of how the event is being handled. This is done from explicitly called event.preventDefault.

Comment: @nnnnnn While it's true that the HTML5 spec. lists inline event handlers as valid attributes of the language, this is for backwards compatibility. These inline handlers have come to be known as "DOM Level 0" event handlers because they are a de facto standard only by developer use. If you look at the actual W3C DOM Event specification (https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html) you will find no mention of them as they are not part of that specification for event handling.

Answer (score 0):

I reworded my original search and found this.  This is really what I was looking for when I came to this site to find the inline solution.

```
<input id="intNumber" type="number" min="1" max="20" />
```

LOL

Comment: You'll still have your original problem if the user doesn't input a value at all because the value will be an empty string, which is Not A Number. Better add the required attribute to that code.